# JointJs how to make links avoid each other. Not to clump up

Tags: hyperlink, jointjs

For several days I'm trying to find solution for my problem. I have a workflow visualizing module made with jointjs. But there are so many links that they clump up and it becomes incomprehensible. I want to make them avoid each other and tend to go parallel rather than over one another. 2nd: no router, jumpover connector) I'm thinking over an idea: When creating a link I'll get all occupied by links pixels and add them to the obstacle map .. somehow. I'm not sure if it's possible since it's a vector graphic. Any one with an idea?

With metro router:
[image: with metro router]

No router, jumpover connector:
[image: no router, jumpover connector]

Comment: Could you please show how did achieve that links on second image jump over other link?

Comment: Links have a _connector_ attribute that you can set to _jumpover_. Check here: [dia.Link.prototype.presentation](http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Link.prototype.presentation).

Example: link.set('connector', { name: 'jumpover', args: { type: 'gap' }});

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution here would be to layout the elements differently, such that the graph is nicely displayed. For this you can use the [JointJS plugin for Dagre](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.1/joint.html#layout.DirectedGraph), which provides you a `joint.layout.DirectedGraph.layout()` function to layout the graph, with several options as well.

A full blog post explaining how this works in more detail can be found [here](http://www.daviddurman.com/automatic-graph-layout-with-jointjs-and-dagre.html).

Hope this can help.